Where can I mount a handrail in my stairwell?
We have a converted attic serving as our second level, and the railing going from the first floor to the second is mounted on just one stud—or at least that's all I can find. I’ve used both a stud finder and magnets but haven’t located any other studs.
I tried using drywall anchors, but they keep getting ripped out over time (as you can see from the three holes beneath the light in the photos). At this point, I’m starting to think the original railing bracket might have been mounted into the cross beam of the first-floor ceiling instead of an actual stud.
My Questions:
Is it normal for split levels to have this kind of stud layout?
Am I missing something? Is there a better method to locate a stud?
If I can’t find another stud and drywall anchors keep failing, what are my best options for securing the railing?



there are usually no studs above the ceiling or below the floor so don't search for studs in the in-between ( the in-between is where trusses and joists are found.)

Do you have access to the space behind the wall?

There will be studs there. Any where from 16" apart to 24" apart. If you are planning on repairing the holes, and I imagine so, to help you start looking, where the light switch is located, my guess there is a stud to the left of the light switch. Remove the cover to see if you can spot one there. There should be one on the right of the step light, not too far away. I would guess that the step light is an add on and it may be possible to be removed completely, if not, it may be possible to spot a stud on the right ride of the step light.
If there is, and you can determine that they are 16" apart, continue the same dimension in the direction you need to go, to hopefully find the next ones. It should get you close.
Using a 3" nail, or something similar, drive the nail into the wall to confirm if there is a stud actually there. If there isn't, use the same hole to angle the nail to the left and right to see if it is possible to hit it that way.
If the wall is drywall, which I think it is, the holes will remain small. Use a level to plumb the holes that do find the studs up to the level you need for the handrail, if they are not already at that level.
Mount your brackets.

There should be a stud there, but there might not be. It is good advice to see if there is a way to actually see behind the wall before doing anything else. This is otherwise an excellent answer.

@Dúthomhas , There will be studs in the wall. There should be a stud at one side or the other at the light switch and possibly the stair light. That is why the removal of the switch and light covers are mentioned. It is a simple, non destructive way to find out. You may be aware of this detail, but I mention it again for the OP.

The electrical box is attached to the stud on the side.  If you take the plate off you can probably see it.  Then the rest of the studs will be 16 inches on center.

that stair light grille is probably attached the the same stud,

Nonstructural studs could be @24"
